# Specify system and root partitions for Windows 7 during install

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-installation, system-reserved-partition

I want to install Windows 7 on a PC that currently has linux installed. My HDD is using the MBR partitioning scheme and its layout is like this:

130MB free space; swap partition(primary); 1.9TB ext4 partition(primary); 100GB free space

I know that Windows 7 needs to create both a boot and a root partition for itself. The question is if (and how) I can ask it to use the first 130MB free space as a boot partition and the last 100G as a root partition.

If that is not possible, I'd like to know what options I'll have regarding partitioning when installing Windows 7.

Comment: You will need to install Windows on the 100GB of free space since 130MB isn't enough for Windows to be installed.

Comment: I'm talking about putting the "System Reserved" partition in the 130MB slot. All "from scratch" installs of Windows 7 I've seen have one and it's never more than 100MB, so it should fit.

Comment: The "System Reserved" partition is not actually required.

Comment: Do you want to retain Linux? If so, you'll need to repair Grub after installing Windows. What you can do is install Win7 to the 100GB partition. One of 2 things will likely happen - either it will use the 130MB unallocated space for the System Reserved partition, or skip creating it altogether.

Comment: Adding a comment to note what happened: I did install to the 100GB section, but windows did not create a separate system partition. After that I reinstalled grub to the mbr and I can boot both linux and windows.

I mostly wanted to be pointed at a detailed guide for partitioning using the windows installer.